# How to use "close" function available in bootstrap-vue Collapse feature

Tags: bootstrap-vue

This is how I am calling the collapse

```
this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'my-collapse-id')
```

but it open and closes both if we click the same button, I would like to close the collapse with close function , aim is to perform something at the time of closing the collapse.

Is there an example of how can we use `close` function of collapse in bootstrap-vue? There is no example in official website [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#optionally-scoped-default-slot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to perform something at the time of closing the collapse

Instead of altering the toggle or trying to use the close function, just use the [`@hide` event](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#comp-ref-b-collapse-events) emitted by `<b-collapse>` when it starts closing to trigger whatever you'd like:

```html
<b-collapse visible @hide="foo()">
  <b-card>C O N T E N T</b-card>
</b-collapse>

...
<script>
...
methods: {
  foo() {
    // do stuff
  },
},
```

This way, any time the collapse starts to close, the `hide` event will fire, and your method will run.

Another thing to note is that the close function you've linked is something that's exposed to children in `<b-collapse>`'s scoped slots, so you won't be able to call it outside of that context anyway.